# Visual Studio "page with blocks" Icon - Where is this documented?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am somewhat obsessed with knowing why my tools do the things that they do.

In C#, when I derive a type from `System.Data.Common.DbConnection` the solution explorer icon changes from [image: c#] to [image: Page With Blocks] (I'm using Visual Studio 2017).

I wanted to find authoritative documentation of why this is happening rather than just shrug it off as "Visual Studio being weird" or guessing that it simply means "a c# file that inherits from DbConnection". **Hopefully, whatever page documents this behavior can also explain any other weird icons in the Solution Explorer**.

I have google image searched this image, I have googled everything from "Visual Studio Inheritance Icon" to "Visual Studio DbConnection Icon" and everything else you could possibly think of, I even attempted to find the icon in the devenv.exe executable's resources so I could find it's name or google image search the exact file, all to no avail.

What I want is to know **where has Microsoft (or some other semi-authoritative resource such as a Microsoft blog) documented what this icon means**? I want to know from an authoritative source what that icon (and hopefully more in the future) is supposed to mean rather than guessing.

Comment: That icon means "hey, a [component](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component)! That's cool man. Here's a nifty icon and designer support if you need it" (if your right-click the file, you'll see a "view designer" option has appeared). This is specific to project types -- a regular console application won't do this, for example, a Forms application will. No, I don't know what makes the component designer magic possible, nor have I ever particularly wondered -- it'll be some funky shell extension magic.

Comment: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.